# Ajax post send data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a javascript file that I want to send data from. I tried using $.ajax and $.post but neither seem to be sending the data to my index.php file.

script.js

```
$.post( "index.php", { over: 'yes' } ).done(function( data ) { alert("success"); });

//AND

$.ajax({
  url: "index.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: {over: "yes"},
  success: function(data){ alert("success"); },
});
```

Both methods receive the success message but neither are echo'ed in my index.php file

```
echo $_POST['over'];
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you

Comment: Print var_dump($_POST) to check variables received or check the console of web browser, you can see if the data it was sended.

Comment: Where are you expecting the echo to go? You are just ignoring any return value and alerting "success".

Comment: $.post( "index.php", { over: 'yes' } ).done(function( data ) { alert(**data**); });

Comment: is index.php in the same folder as the page that is running the script.js?

Comment: @WEBjuju yes, same folder

Comment: @JSLirola var_dump returned this "array(0) { }"

Comment: @GoneCoding How do i return a value?

Comment: Sorry by value I meant any returned data or HTML:. Basically whatever the PHP returns is passed to your data parameter. If you specify a `dataType` it will automatically convert to certain formats (JSON, XML etc).